# How do I handle multiple forms in Django with many-to-many relationship

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

In my view I have a the Booking information, in  the booking I have a many-to-many relationship to the size of the group in the booking and the age. The class (group size, age) has the many-to-many relationship. When the booking is made I would like the user to be able to add class details. So a booking can have many classes.

I have tried using `inline_formset_factory` but it did not like the many-to-many relationship and according to the docs `inline_formset_factory` is for a `ForeignKey` relationship (I could easily be wrong here). Also it seems I need a booking instance before I can use the `inline_formset_factory` (Though again I could be wrong)

So to recap I'm new to django and I'm trying to add many classes to a booking via a form which is with the booking form. I'm just not sure if I'm on the right track.

I hope this made sense. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating the form yourself, instead use a [`ModelForm`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#module-django.forms.models) which will tie your form to a model in your app, automatically creating the field types it needs to save or edit an instance of the model it is linked with.

---

The simplest way to add a `Booking` instance to you database would be to use a [`ModelForm`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#module-django.forms.models):

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Booking(models.Model):
    ...

class BookingForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
```

See [the Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#module-django.forms.models) for more information on `ModelForm`s. Next in your view create an instance of the `BookingForm` passing it in your template context:

```
def your_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            booking = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
    else:
        form = BookingForm()

    return direct_to_template(request, 'your/template.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

For more information on dealing with forms in your views see [using a form in a view](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view) in the Django docs. Next in your template you can simply print the entire form (and all the relevant fields) like so:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

See [displaying a form using a template](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#displaying-a-form-using-a-template) for more information on forms in templates.

Comment: Thanks Marcus. But I am already using `ModelForm` for my forms. Perhaps I have not explained myself properly. I have a form for the Booking. But within the form I need to add many classes (which is a form itself) I hope to do this with one form. instead of 2 seperate

Comment: I see, I unfortunately don't have much experience with this kind of inline creation.